# Hide image from gallery

Tags: android

I need to hide image(not folder) in both file browser and **gallery** without changing the file location. I tried prefixing the file name with `.` it hides the image in the file browser but still showing in gallery. Is there any way to hide image from **gallery**?

Comment: No there is no way

Comment: @NJ Is there is any alternatives??

Comment: In Android, all images on the external sd card are public. That cannot be changed. I believe you can make your app's personal pictures private. Thus, only showing where you want them. If the image is on the external, maybe you can copy the file to your app's personal folder and delete off the external, thus giving you complete control of where it is displayed. This is just an idea.

Comment: @Buildersrejected Thanks for your suggestion, I think thats the only way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to hide image(not folder) in both file browser and gallery
>   without changing the file location.

My thought over this problem is 
**You can change the extension(make file without any extension)** so media scanner will not able to detect it.

e.g file name us **test.png**  rename it to only **test**

Comment: I tried removing the extension, but even after it shows in the gallery. I changed the extension using the renameTo() method, is I need to try any other way?

Comment: I have checked the image file details it still listed as a jpeg file. I think it uses the file format structure to detect the file type.

Comment: you are missing some thing while renaming  , simply you can check from file browser on real device rename file then it will disappear from gallery

Answer (score 6):

Create a `.nomedia` file in the same (or parent) directory of the image. This will hide all media in the current directory and subdirectories. (The media scanner will not scan this directory).

Comment: I think it hides the entire directory!!

Comment: He said he didn't want all images hidden

Comment: @Ajay This will not hide other files, only media. (e.g. images)

Comment: @SuperThomasLab But I don't need to hide all the media files, some of the images in  a folder as the yours wish to hide